# How to sum all values in a column only if they are numerical?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
def check(df, columns):
   for col in columns:
      if df[col].sum(axis=0) == 0:
         return True
   return false
```

This code goes through the columns of `df` and checks is the sum of all values in a column is equal to 0 (i.e. all values are 0, while ignoring empty fields).

However it fails if one of the columns in `columns` in non-numeric. How can I add a condition that `df[col].sum(axis=0) == 0` should only work on numeric columns and it should ignore empty rows if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[0,0,np.nan,0,-0,0],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})


print (df)
   A    B  C  E  F
0  a  0.0  7  5  a
1  b  0.0  8  3  a
2  c  NaN  9  6  a
3  d  0.0  4  9  b
4  e  0.0  2  2  b
5  f  0.0  3  4  b

def check(df, columns):
    return df[columns].select_dtypes(np.number).fillna(0).eq(0).all().any()

print (check(df, df.columns))
True
```

Another alternative with test missing values and chained boolean DataFrame by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
def check(df, columns):
    df1 = df[columns].select_dtypes(np.number)
    return (df1.eq(0) | df1.isna()).all().any()
```

**Explanation**:

First select columns specified in list, in sample all column and get only numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
print (df[columns].select_dtypes(np.number))
     B  C  E
0  0.0  7  5
1  0.0  8  3
2  NaN  9  6
3  0.0  4  9
4  0.0  2  2
5  0.0  3  4
```

Then replace missing values by `0` with [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
print (df[columns].select_dtypes(np.number).fillna(0))
     B  C  E
0  0.0  7  5
1  0.0  8  3
2  0.0  9  6
3  0.0  4  9
4  0.0  2  2
5  0.0  3  4
```

Compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) for `==`:

```
print (df[columns].select_dtypes(np.number).fillna(0).eq(0))
      B      C      E
0  True  False  False
1  True  False  False
2  True  False  False
3  True  False  False
4  True  False  False
5  True  False  False
```

Test if all columns are only `True`s by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (df[columns].select_dtypes(np.number).fillna(0).eq(0).all())
B     True
C    False
E    False
dtype: bool
```

And last test if at least one in Series in `True` by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
print (df[columns].select_dtypes(np.number).fillna(0).eq(0).all().any())
True
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you use `any`? Does it return a single boolean value or a list?

Comment: @Tatik - Sure, give me some time

Comment: Thanks, but probably I have not explained well my question. Let's imagine a column `col1` with values 0, 0, 0, NaN, 0. Since all values are 0 and I want to ignore NaN, then the answer is True. If a column `col1` has values 0, 0, 0, NaN, 5, -5, then the answer is False, because two rows have non-zero values (5 and -5).

Comment: @Tatik - Sure, so need scalar output? True or False from function?

Comment: It's ok now. Thanks.

Comment: @Tatik - Added better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this condition as well :

```
if df[col].dtype == int or df[col].dtype == float:
    #your code
```